# Automatically enter username and password using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am hitting a url using http post with certain parameters and upon hitting url a box appears which asks for username and password . For now i am pasting the url in browser and on entering it asks for username and password.

I want to do this using asp.net when i know how to send request to url but i want to know how can i automatically enter username and password using code . Thank You

Comment: It's not guarantied nor safe, but you can use `SendKeys.Send` method to send your username, a tab (to focus on password textbox), password and then enter (to submit).

Comment: What i actually want is to get the webpages response and fill in the form automatically through code

Comment: Are you using ASP.net FORMS or ASP.net MVC.  Either way there is a way to set the values of text boxes.  In MVC you do it inside your view and in FORMS you can set it by finding the element inside the page and then setting the .Text property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is send a POST request to the server with the username and password. Most servers will not accept a direct authentication request and will require to have a few Http headers like cookies, referer to be set before it.

You can use a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what your browser is actually sending to the server.

Here is a small sample to send post data to the server.

```
// create the POST request
var postParams = "user=userName&password=userPassword";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yourUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = postParams.Length;

// send POST data
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(postParams);
}
```

**EDIT**: This is this simplest method to set the basic authorization header

```
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "userPassword");
```

The link you provide says that they use basic HTTP authentication.

Comment: http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/evolution.sms.postapi

This is what we are doing here and they have mentioned we need to include http authorization header and then they have given an example of CURL and php for how to do it . I am trying to do similar thing from within .net environment without having to use php

Comment: I would like to set http header using asp instead of curl+ php as mentioned in tutorial

Comment: For that you need to set the authorization header. Or simpler, just set the credentials. I will update my answer.